# Scrollable UITextField

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to make the UITextField (horizontally) scrollable?

Thanks,
Mihai

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a multi-line `UITextField`? If that is the case you need `UITextView`. By default it is multi-lines.

Comment: Not necessarily multi-line, as one single line that scrolls horizontally. Thanks.

Comment: Why would that be required? To display the white space beneath the text?

Comment: No, I just have a text that is not small enough to fit in a text field. Since all other text fields are one line, I wanted to have the same. I will end up using text views instead of text fields everywhere on that particular screen, so to keep the uniformity intact. The problem with text views is that they do not have rounded edges like text fields do. I will end up setting the opacity to 0 to only display the text.